# Where to put shared code for tests in a Go package?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a Go package with multiple files. As of Go standard I am creating an associated test file for each source file in the package.

In my case the different tests use the same test helping functions. I don't want these functions to be in the package source files because it is only used for testing purpose. I also would like avoiding replicating this code in each test file.

Where should I put this code shared between all the test source files and not part of the package ?

Comment: If it's only for tests, in any `_test.go` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just put it in any of the test files and that's all. Test files using the same package clause belong to the same test package and can refer to each other's exported *and* unexported identifiers without any `import` statements.

Also note that you're not required to create a separate `_test.go` file for each of the `.go` files; and you can have an `xx_test.go` file without having a "matching" `xx.go` file in the package.

For example if you're writing package `a`, having the following files:

```
a/
    a.go
    b.go
    a_test.go
    b_test.go
```

For black-box testing you'd use the `package a_test` package clause in `a_test.go` and `b_test.go`. Having a `func util()` in file `a_test.go`, you can use it in `b_test.go` too.

If you're writing white-box testing, you'd use `package a` in the test files, and again, you can refer any identifiers declared in `a_test.go` from `b_test.go` (and vice versa) without any imports.

Note that however if the package clauses in `a_test.go` and `b_test.go` do not match (e.g. `a_test.go` uses `package a` and `b_test.go` uses `package a_test`), then they will belong to different test packages and then you can't use identifiers declared in one another.

Comment: What do you do if you want to reuse test code across packages? Go does not allow to import test code.

Comment: @PeterDotchev You can't import code being part of a test package, but if you want to reuse code in multiple tests, put it in a non-test package, so you can import it from tests as well.

Comment: If I put test code in a non-test package, will it be included in my production binary?

Comment: @PeterDotchev Only if non-test packages also import it, else it won't.